# Olympiad level number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a + b + c + abc + ab + bc + ac$ = 1000 then $a + b + c=?$  . I don't know how to approach? Any hints welcome.

Comment: $a+b+c+abc+ab+bc+ac = (a+1)(b+1)(c+1)-1$

Comment: NB You need to say that $a,b,c$ are positive integers. If integers only are specified you will get some solutions with negative numbers. If you go to rationals or reals, any choice of $a,b$ leaves a linear equation for $c$ except in special cases.

Answer (score 7):

*Hint:* $a+b+c+abc+ab+bc+ac = (1+a)(1+b)(1+c)-1$

Answer (score 6):

Hint: If you write $1+a+b+c+ab+bc+ca+abc=1001$ can you factorise both sides?

This assumes you are looking for positive integer solutions.